# How to find points with specific degree on the contour (Opencv)

Tags: opencv, point, contour, angle

I have the points of the contour and i want to get the (x,y) of the points that are on specific degree. From the attached image, i want to get the yellow points.

[image: Get the yellow points that are on 0,45,90,135,180,125,270,and 360 degree.]

Comment: What do you mean by "degree"? Are you looking for intersections of the counour with some lines separated by an angle? Also, have you tried anything at all?

Comment: No i didn't try any thing because i don't know how to do it. But i'll try your hint, thank you.

Comment: Well it wasn't intended as a hint but a request for clarification, but I suppose when you look at the problem from such perspective it becomes somewhat easier. I know you can approximate the contour with polynomials in `OpenCV`. If you do this and describe the lines as polynomials of order 1 you can analytically find the intersection points. Nice, easy and quick.

Comment: you can find intersection points fairly easily by drawing contour and the lines on two seperate images and perform logical AND. then the resulting image will be your yellow points. is the centre of the red cross the centroid?

Comment: @ZawLin yes i'm trying to solve it by ANDing two separate images. But now i have a problem drawing the lines. I'll provide the code to discuss it if couldn't get any further :D.

Answer (score 1):

I used the hint that @Aleksander and @Zaw gave me.
The centroid of the contour was used as one point to draw the lines and i used the line equations to get the second point of each line and draw it.

```
y - y1 = m (x - x1)
```

to get **m** we used the following equations

```
arctan( **y** of the centroid / **x** of the centroid) - angle in radiant = Phi

tan(Phi) = m
```

then i used

```
y = m (x - x1) + y1
```

when x1 and y1 is the centroid point, and x is the assumed coordinate of the second point needed to draw the line.

```
void MyDraw (Mat Draw, vector<Point> hull,Scalar color,int thickness){
  std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > T = std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> >(1,hull); 
  drawContours(Draw, T, -1, color, thickness);} 

Point GetCentroidOfConvexHull(vector<Point> Hull){
// Get the moments
  Moments mu;
  mu= moments(Hull, false );
// Get the mass centers:
  return Point( mu.m10/mu.m00 , mu.m01/mu.m00 );}   



void _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){ 
    vector<vector<Point>> contours;
    vector<Point> hull;
    Mat testContour = Mat::zeros(width, height,CV_8UC3);
    Mat testLine = Mat::zeros(width, height,CV_8UC3);
    Mat andResult;
    Point centroid;

    findContours(Dilated,contour,hierarchy,CV_RETR_EXTERNAL,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE,Point (0,0));
    convexHull(contour,hull,false);
    centroid = GetCentroidOfConvexHull(hull);
    MyDraw(testContour,hull,White,1);
    Rect myRect = boundingRect(hull);
    imshow("test contour",testContour);
    waitKey(0);
    float degrees[8] = {0,45,90,135,180,225,270,315};
    Point point;
    // for each degree                
    for (int d = 0 ; d < 8 ; d++){
       //Get line equation from the slope and the center point of the contour
       float m = std::tan( std::atan2((double)centroid.y,(double)centroid.x) - (degrees[d]*3.14/180));
       // using the upper left and lower right points to get the x of the other point
       if ((d >= 0 && d <= 2) || d == 7) point.x = myRect.tl().x;
       else point.x = myRect.br().x;
       point.y = (int)(m * (float)(point.x - centroid.x) + centroid.y);
       line(testLine,centroid,point,White,1,8);}

       imshow("test Line",testLine);
       waitKey(0);
       // and operation
       andResult = testContour & testLine;
       imshow("Anding Result",andResult);
       waitKey(0);}
```

After drawing the contour and the lines, i did a bit wise **AND** operation to get the intersection between the lines and the contour.

[image: contour and lines]

[image: Extracted points]